# How to call a class declared in the manifests folder from outside this folder?

Tags: puppet

I have a module structure such as this:

```
my_module
|__ server.pp
|__ manifests
   |__ dashboard.pp
```

I am trying to call `my_module::dashboard` from `server`.

```
class { 'my_module::dashboard': }
```

But Puppet can't find it.

Comment: Why is your `server.pp` class not in your manifests folder?

Comment: I know it should be but when it is I can't seem to call it from outside my upper manifests folder which hosts all of my custom modules?

Comment: You need to have the `server.pp` inside your manifests folder, it sounds like if that isn't working you might have a `modulepath` or folder layout issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place manifests in a directory that is outside the autoloading paths. Manifests must be located in a `manifests` directory inside a module that is inside of a `modulepath`.

There is concise and helpful documentation here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_namespaces.html#autoloader-behavior

You can also test for autoloading issues with [Puppet-Lint](https://rubygems.org/gems/puppet-lint) so you can track down these errors faster.